# Facebook Graph API: Getting total of shares of a page's photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of shares of a photo of a Facebok's Page. But I can't do that!
The photo's table just have likes/comments info. And, the table "stream" just works with posts, doesn't work with photos.

Photo's ID: 313125495503479

Page's ID: 285150194967676

There's anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When the object it's a photo, you can do this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+share_count+from+stream+where+post_id+IN+(select+page_story_id+from+photo+where+object_id+=\"{$object_id}\"+)&access_token={$tk}
```

when the object it's a stream, or something like this, you can d this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+share_count+from+stream+where+post_id+=\"{$object_id}\"&access_token={$tk}
```

Parse json, and get the field 'share_count'...Worked for me!